# Python Get dictionary value with a key list

Tags: python

Considering I have

```
users = \
{
    'Sam': {
        'age': 19,
        'location': 'Flodira',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    'Max': {
        'age': 16,
        'location': 'Sydney',
        'country': 'Australia'
    }
}

def getUserValue(query):
    return users[query]

getUserValue(['Sam', 'location'])
```

How could I do this? I know I could straightly do `users['Sam']['location']`, what I would like to do is get Sam's location via a list object.

Comment: Create a function that takes a list as an argument and simply does `users['Sam']['location']` using the values from the list..

Comment: Do you want the stored data or the keys to be a list? Could that "list object" be two lists, or a list containing two lists, or something else? What kind of performance do you want, and would order n be good enough? Finally, what is wrong with `users['Sam']['location']`?

Comment: @Farhan.K I know the function could be `def getUserValue(user, value)`, but it is not the case, I'd like to get X's value by using a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic solution that handles different levels of nesting:

```
def getUserValue(users, query):
    v = users
    for i in query:
        v = v[i]
    return v

print(getUserValue(users, ['Sam', 'location']))
# Flodira
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getUserValue(query):
    assert(len(query) == 2)
    return users[query[0]][query[1]]
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem with recursion:

```
def getByList(d, l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return d
    else:
        return getByList(d[l[0]], l[1:])

def getUserValue(query):
     return getByList(users, query)
```

Comment: you could also just test `if l` and flip flop your returns.. an empty list is falsey

Comment: True, but I think this is more explicit. It's not clear if I'm checking whether `l` is a nonempty list or if `l` is not `None` or anything else falsey.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution than Jared's, you could use list unpacking with a recursive function..

```
def getUserValue(dic, lis):
    if len(lis) > 1:
        return getUserValue(dic[lis[0]], lis[1:])
    else:
        return dic[lis[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
users = \
{
    'Sam': {
        'age': 19,
        'location': 'Flodira',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    'Max': {
        'age': 16,
        'location': 'Sydney',
        'country': 'Australia'
    }
}

def getUserValue(my_args):
    item = users[my_args.pop(0)]
    while my_args:
        item = item[my_args.pop(0)]
    return item

print(getUserValue(['Sam', 'location']))  # prints -> Flodira
```

keeps treating `item` as a dictionary until the passed list is depleted.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain old [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem)

```
import operator

def getUserValue(dic, lis):
    return reduce(operator.getitem, lis, dic)
```