# Accessing Python Dictionarys with ["key","key2"]

Tags: python, dictionary

I am developing a python utility. Part of this is to generate an index of files
Is it possible within python to access a multidimensional dictionary dynamically without knowing the depth.
ie if i had the example data:
`example = {'main': {'2': {'2': '2-2', '1': '2-1'}, '1': {'2': '1-2', '1': '1-1'}}}`
Is there a way i can access elements with something similar to
`example["main","2","1"]` and it return `2-1`?
I am aware i can write my own diving algorithms but my experience shows you cannot then write to the value.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot then write to the value"?

Comment: You can always do `example['main']['2']['1']`. Of course you'd have to know your keys ('main', '2' and '1')

Comment: Why do you rather need `example["main","2","1"]` than `example["main"]["2"]["1"]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Get dictionary value with a key list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493063/python-get-dictionary-value-with-a-key-list)

Comment: you should be able to write to the value just fine.. just modify the getter to be a setter

Comment: @Aaron It is similar to [Python Get dictionary value with a key list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493063/python-get-dictionary-value-with-a-key-list) but in this there has been no advice on how to set that value accessed with a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely positively need to do it that way, you'll need to roll your own dict class. Luckily you can inherit everything but `__getitem__` from `dict`.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        if isinstance(keys, str):
            # this special-case saves you if you try to do normal indexing
            # on a string.
            return super().__getitem__(keys)
        cur = self
        for key in keys:
            cur = cur.get(key, {})
            # the default option here returns an empty dict instead
            # of raising a KeyError. That might not be what you want
        return cur
```

Note that this removes your ability to key by tuple, so key/vals like `{("some", "tuple", "values"): "any value"}` will be inaccessible unless specifically coded for. That might look something like...

```
...
        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            if keys[i:] in cur:
                return cur[keys[i:]]
            cur = cur.get(key, {})
```

You can then cast your mapping to this new dict and search that way.

```
example = {'main': {'2': {'2': '2-2', '1': '2-1'}, '1': {'2': '1-2', '1': '1-1'}}}
result = MyDict2(example)['2', '2', '1']
```

You mention having to set values by this as well, in which case also inherit `__setitem__`.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        # as above
    def __setitem__(self, keys, value):
        if isinstance(keys, str):
            super().__setitem__(keys, value)
        cur = self
        for key in keys[:-1]:
            cur = cur.setdefault(key, {})
        cur[keys[-1]] = value
```

Comment: he mentioned assignment to those nested dict values, so you might want to add the `__setitem__()` as well

Comment: @Aaron hmm it's not working, deleting 'till I get it tested and runnable -- but good point!

Comment: Shouldn't `super().__setitem__(keys, value)` be `return super().__setitem__(keys, value)` without the return, it creates a load of weird entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function like this:

```python
def get_item(d, keys):
    current = d
    for k in keys:
        current = current[k] # You can add some error handling here
    return current
```

Example of usage: https://repl.it/E49o/1

If you want to modify the value at the last index, you can do something like this.

```python
def set_item(d, keys, new_value):
    current = d
    for k in keys[:-1]: # All the keys except the last one
        current = current[k] 
    current[keys[-1]] = new_value
```

Comment: I had created something similar, problem is there is no way (that i can see) to use a similar function to set the value.

Comment: I modified my answer with a setter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap the idea proposed by @Arya in a derived dict class, e.g.:

```
class ListAccess(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if type(item) in [tuple,list]:
            item = list(item)
            ret = self
            while True:
                try:
                    ret = ret[item.pop(0)]
                except IndexError:
                    break
            return ret
        else:
            return super(ListAccess, self).__getitem__(item)

store = ListAccess({'main': {'2': {'2': '2-2', '1': '2-1'}, '1': {'2': '1-2', '1': '1-1'}}})
print store['main','2','1']
```